# _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM

Tags: acpi, dmesg

I get this `dmesg` message, what does it mean?

> acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
>
> acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1349740 the comments there pretty much explain what the problem is.

Comment: From the bug report: It usually means a firmware bug in the hardware BIOS, not a kernel bug, not an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: @user535733 so what? I search for a solution in Ubuntu, not for an assassin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This error message occurs when the kernel runs the root PCI bridge
>   _OSC control method in your firmware and the execution fails, perhaps due to a bug in the firmware or perhaps it does not exist. The kernel
>   hence cannot determine the features supported or capabilities provided
>   by the device (as specified by your firmware) and hence has to disable
>   PCIe ASPM ([Active State Power Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management)).
>
> The downside of Active State Power Management not being enabled is
>   that the machine is less power efficient, however, one can force this
>   on with the kernel boot parameter "pcie_aspm=force" however, forcing
>   this on may cause system lockups.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1349740#yui_3_10_3_1_1558698386404_1728)